# Invoking a middleware functions on AWS lambda ( without express )

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

Basically i want to invoke [passport-cognito](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-cognito) login authentication in a lambda , but i cant seem to invoke this without using express , ive tried invoking the function with req,res variables but i still cant seem to get the authentication working

```
module.exports = (user, callback) => {
  let req = {
    body: user
  };
  let res = {
    end: (...params) => {
      console.log(params);
    }
  }
  passport.authenticate('cognito', {
    successRedirect: callback(null,{"message": "success"}),
    failureRedirect: callback(null,{"message": "failed"})
  })(req, res);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend calling API Gateway to invoke your lambda function.  You can use cognito pools for authentication as AWS outline in this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-user-pools-with-api-gateway/

Comment: well cognito is one use case , i need to get it working with passport , so i can use it with azure-ad as well ..